# Trigonometric inequality with a parameter

Tags: trigonometry

Suppose $\kappa>0$ is some parameter. For what $x$ does the bound hold:
$$
\kappa\cot(\sqrt{\kappa} x) - \sin(\sqrt{\kappa} x) \geq 0
$$
I know that for $\kappa \geq 1$, one can deduce that for $0 \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{\kappa}}$, the above inequality holds. But I cannot derive a bound for $\kappa < 1$.

For $\kappa<1$, it can hold (provided $0 \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{\kappa}}$) $$ \frac{\sin(\sqrt{\kappa} x)\tan(\sqrt{\kappa} x)}{\kappa} \leq 1$$ But I cannot derive a bound on $x$ from that.

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\kappa\cot(\sqrt{\kappa} x) - \sin(\sqrt{\kappa} x) \geq 0$ is equivalent to $\kappa\cos(\sqrt{\kappa} x) \ge \sin(\sqrt{\kappa} x)^2 = 1-\cos^2(\sqrt{\kappa} x)$. Therefore $c=\cos(\sqrt{\kappa} x)$ satisfies the quadratic inequality $c^2 + \kappa c - 1 \ge 0$, which means that
$$
\cos(\sqrt{\kappa} x) = c \le \frac{-\kappa-\sqrt{\kappa^2+4}}2 \quad\text{or}\quad \cos(\sqrt{\kappa} x) = c \ge \frac{-\kappa+\sqrt{\kappa^2+4}}2.
$$
Restricting to positive values of $c$, we see that
$$
0 < x \le c \le \frac1{\sqrt\kappa} \arccos \bigg( \frac{-\kappa+\sqrt{\kappa^2+4}}2 \bigg),
$$
and negative values of $c$ can be handled similarly.
(Of course the set of solutions $x$ is periodic modulo $2\pi/\sqrt\kappa$.)

Comment: Thank you for the solution.